# SQL to NHibernate queryover with SQL function Values

Tags: sql, c, nhibernate, left-join, queryover

I am trying to make a queryover that returns a list of objects called StatusTaxatieAantal.

```
    public class StatusTaxatieAantal
{
    public long Aantal { get; set; }
    public long StatusTaxatie { get; set; }
}
```

I already have the SQL query that returns the list but now i need to convert it to NHibernate queryover. I have no experience with this way of writing queries. Here is the SQL query ive created and the result.

```
SELECT SUB.count,x.StatTax
FROM (VALUES (30),(28),(22),(20),(18),(16),(14),(12),(11),(10),(0)) x(StatTax)
left join
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, wb.StatTax
FROM dbo.Wbp wb 
INNER JOIN dbo.tax ta ON wb.WozNum = ta.WozNum AND wb.WrdPeildat = ta.WrdPeildat 
INNER JOIN dbo.Woz wo ON wo.WozNum = ta.WozNum  
WHERE wb.wrdpeildat = 20170101 AND wb.IsLaatste = 1  AND (wo.Soc < '2000' or wo.Soc = '5100') 
GROUP BY wb.StatTax
)
SUB ON x.StatTax = SUB.StatTax
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/28u9c.jpg

count would be the Aantal and StatTax would be StatusTaxatie. If anyone knows how to convert this to queryover or has a website that explains it i would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<StatusTaxatieAantal> nietWoningList =
            Session.QueryOver(() => wbp)
                .JoinAlias(() => wbp.Tax, () => tax)
                .JoinAlias(() => tax.Woz, () => woz)
                .JoinAlias(() => woz.Soc, () => soc)
                .Where(() => wbp.Waardepeildatum == waardePeilDatum)
                .And(() => wbp.IsLaatste)
                .And(
                    Restrictions.And(
                        Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Property(() => soc.Id), "2000"),
                       !Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property(() => soc.Id), "5100"))
                )
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .SelectCount(() => wbp.WozNummer).WithAlias(() => result.Aantal)
                    .SelectGroup(() => wbp.StatusTaxatie).WithAlias(() => result.StatusTaxatie)
                )
                .OrderBy(() => wbp.StatusTaxatie).Desc
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<StatusTaxatieAantal>())
                .List<StatusTaxatieAantal>();
```

after this i make an list with all statusses and check if the return list has de status or not.